# string comparison in c

Tags: c, string, char, microblaze

I am writing a c program for my microblaze on the fpga now i want to check if i recieved the message ok but strncmp and strcmp are not working the only way that is working is this way :

```
           char*as=malloc(sizeof(int));

    as=p->payload;
            if (*(as)=='o') {//first letter o
    if (*(as+1)=='k') {//second letter
```

but this will be hard once i deal with longer text , so any good approach ?
i tried strncmp in this format :

```
         if (strncmp(as,"ok",2)==0)      //didnt work even changing 0 to 1 it just doesnt detectct it
```

Comment: `strncmp` takes 3 arguments - are you including string.h?

Comment: Why call malloc and then throw away the pointer?

Comment: i am including string.h and not typing 3rd argument was a mistake
I throw away the pointer because i have to do it this way or it will give an error  as p->payload is void* not char*

Comment: You might want to format the code a little to make it easier to read. It would also help to see what "p" and "p->payload" are.

Comment: with your assignment, it seems that you are leaking the memory that you just allocated with `malloc`. Also using `sizeof(int)` as the length parameter looks bizarre in the context that you are giving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the syntax of "strncmp"

```
int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num );
```

where `str1` is the C string to be compared, `str2` is the C string to be compared and `num` is the maximum number of characters to compare.

I think introducing the third variable `num` i.e the maximum no of character you want to compare  will solve your problem.

Comment: How is this different from my earlier answer?

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/:

```
int strncmp(const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num);
```

Did you perhaps forget to supply **num**, the maximum number of characters to compare?

The function **strncmp** uses it, but **strcmp** does not! If comparing whole strings, the latter one is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try to recompile your program with the warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`).

My guess is that you forgot to include the definition of the `strncmp` at the begining of the source file like this:

```
#include <string.h>
```

So, when the warnings will be activated you should see appear the following message:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'strncmp()'
```

Try to always activate the warnings when compiling, it's very helpful.

Comment: +1 You can "always activate the warnings" by putting `CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra'` in your bash `.profile` and always use `make` to compile.